# Read binary file containing strings and numbers in Fortran

Tags: fortran, binaryfiles

I am trying to read a binary file in Fortran. The file contains strings and numbers. I know how the binary file was created, since I have the code. Here is the minimal reproducible example of code that creates such a binary file:

```
PROGRAM MAIN
    
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
    
    IMPLICIT NONE
    
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I32 = INT32
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: R32 = REAL32
    CHARACTER(1_I32) , PARAMETER :: END_REC = CHAR(10_I32) !end-character for binary-record finalize
    CHARACTER(*), PARAMETER :: MAIN_FILE_NAME = "main_file"
    INTEGER(KIND=I32) :: E_IO, I, UNIT_MAIN, UNIT_SCRATCH
    INTEGER(KIND=I32) :: N_BYTE !number of byte to be written/read
    INTEGER(KIND=I32) :: IOFFSET, IOFFSET_1, IOFFSET_2
    INTEGER(KIND=I32) , PARAMETER :: MAXLEN = 500_I32
    CHARACTER(LEN=MAXLEN)    :: S_BUFFER
    REAL(KIND=R32) :: RPRO
    INTEGER(KIND=I32) :: IPRO
    INTEGER(KIND=I32), PARAMETER :: N_INT_VAL = 2, N_REAL_VAL = 3
    REAL(KIND=R32), DIMENSION(N_REAL_VAL) :: X, Y, Z
    INTEGER(KIND=I32), DIMENSION(N_INT_VAL) :: INT_ARRAY
    CHARACTER(2) :: VAR_TYPE
    INTEGER(KIND=I32) :: N_V
    REAL(KIND=R32), ALLOCATABLE :: V_R4(:)
    REAL(KIND=I32), ALLOCATABLE :: V_I4(:)
    !initlialization of data arrays
    X = (/0.0_R32, 1.0_R32, 3.0_R32/)
    Y = (/0.0_R32, 2.0_R32, 1.0_R32/)
    Z = (/0.0_R32, 4.0_R32, 3.0_R32/)
    INT_ARRAY = (/1_I32, 100_I32/)
    
    UNIT_MAIN = 11
    UNIT_SCRATCH = 12
    
    !open the binary file
    OPEN(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, FILE=MAIN_FILE_NAME,                         &
         FORM='UNFORMATTED', ACCESS='STREAM',             &
         ACTION='WRITE', CONVERT='BIG_ENDIAN', IOSTAT=E_IO)
    
    !open SCRATCH file for appending raw binary data
    OPEN(UNIT=UNIT_SCRATCH,                                                               &
         FORM='UNFORMATTED', ACCESS='STREAM',                                   &
         ACTION='READWRITE', CONVERT='BIG_ENDIAN', STATUS='SCRATCH', IOSTAT=E_IO)
    IOFFSET = 0_I32 ! initializing offset
    
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO)'<version="1.0"? byte_order="BigEndian>'//END_REC
    
    !------prepare real points X, Y, Z------
    WRITE(S_BUFFER, FMT='(A,'//'(I12)'//',A)', IOSTAT=E_IO)'<NumberOfRealPoints="',N_REAL_VAL,'">'
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO)TRIM(S_BUFFER)//END_REC
    
    WRITE(S_BUFFER,FMT='(I8)', IOSTAT=E_IO)IOFFSET
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO)'<DataArray type="Float32" NumberOfComponents="3" offset="',TRIM(S_BUFFER),'">'//END_REC
    
    N_BYTE  = 3_I32*N_REAL_VAL*SIZEOF(RPRO)
    IOFFSET = IOFFSET + sizeof(IPRO) + N_BYTE  !0 + size(N_BYTE) + size(X+Y+Z) = 40 bytes
    IOFFSET_1 = IOFFSET
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_SCRATCH, IOSTAT=E_IO) N_BYTE,'R4',3_I32*N_REAL_VAL
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_SCRATCH, IOSTAT=E_IO)(X(I),Y(I),Z(I),   I=1_I32, N_REAL_VAL) !write real points to SCRATCH file
    !--------------------------------------------------
    !------prepare integer array INT_ARRAY------
    WRITE(S_BUFFER, FMT='(A,'//'(I12)'//',A)', IOSTAT=E_IO)'<NumberOfIntValues="',N_INT_VAL,'">'
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO)TRIM(S_BUFFER)//END_REC
    
    WRITE(S_BUFFER,FMT='(I8)', IOSTAT=E_IO)IOFFSET
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO)'<DataArray type="Int32" NumberOfComponents="1" offset="',TRIM(S_BUFFER),'">'//END_REC
    
    N_BYTE  = 1_I32*N_INT_VAL*SIZEOF(IPRO)
    IOFFSET = IOFFSET + sizeof(IPRO) + N_BYTE  !size(N_BYTE) + size(X+Y+Z) + size(N_BYTE) + size(INT_ARRAY)  = 40 bytes + 12 bytes = 52 bytes
    IOFFSET_2 = IOFFSET
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_SCRATCH, IOSTAT=E_IO) N_BYTE,'I4',1_I32*N_INT_VAL
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_SCRATCH, IOSTAT=E_IO)(INT_ARRAY(I),   I=1_I32, N_INT_VAL)
    !--------------------------------------------------
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO)'<end text>'//END_REC
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO)'_'
    
    
    ENDFILE(UNIT=UNIT_SCRATCH, IOSTAT=E_IO)
    REWIND(UNIT=UNIT_SCRATCH, IOSTAT=E_IO)
    DO
      READ(UNIT=UNIT_SCRATCH, IOSTAT=E_IO, END=100) N_BYTE, VAR_TYPE, N_V
      SELECT CASE(VAR_TYPE)
          CASE('R4')
            ALLOCATE(V_R4(1_I32:N_V))
            READ (UNIT=UNIT_SCRATCH, IOSTAT=E_IO)(V_R4(I),I=1_I32,N_V)
            WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO) N_BYTE, (V_R4(I),I=1_I32,N_V)
            DEALLOCATE(V_R4)
          
          CASE('I4')
              ALLOCATE(V_I4(1_I32:N_V))
              READ (UNIT=UNIT_SCRATCH, IOSTAT=E_IO)(V_I4(I),I=1_I32,N_V)
              WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO) N_BYTE, (V_I4(I),I=1_I32,N_V)
              DEALLOCATE(V_I4)
      END SELECT
        
    END DO
    
    100 CONTINUE
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO)END_REC
    WRITE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO)'<end file>'//END_REC
    
    CLOSE(UNIT=UNIT_SCRATCH, IOSTAT=E_IO)
    CLOSE(UNIT=UNIT_MAIN, IOSTAT=E_IO)
    
    CALL READ_FILE(MAIN_FILE_NAME,N_INT_VAL,N_REAL_VAL,IOFFSET_1,IOFFSET_2)
    
END PROGRAM MAIN
```

The code writes into file text header (7 strings) and then the arrays `X, Y, Z, INT_ARRAY` and the footer at the end. I am able to read the text (7 string) using `READ_FILE` subroutine:

```
SUBROUTINE READ_FILE(MAIN_FILE_NAME,N_INT_VAL,N_REAL_VAL,IOFFSET_1,IOFFSET_2)
    
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
    
    IMPLICIT NONE
    
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I32 = INT32
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: R32 = REAL32
    INTEGER(KIND=I32) :: E_IO, I, N_V
    CHARACTER(*), INTENT(IN) :: MAIN_FILE_NAME
    INTEGER(KIND=I32), INTENT(IN) :: N_INT_VAL, N_REAL_VAL
    INTEGER(KIND=I32), INTENT(IN) :: IOFFSET_1, IOFFSET_2
    CHARACTER(LEN=100) :: DUMMY
    CHARACTER(LEN=1) :: ONECH
    INTEGER(KIND=I32) :: N_BYTE
    REAL(KIND=R32), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: REAL_ARRAY_READ
    INTEGER(KIND=I32), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: INT_ARRAY_READ
    
    ALLOCATE(REAL_ARRAY_READ(3_I32*N_REAL_VAL), INT_ARRAY_READ(N_INT_VAL))
    
    
    OPEN(UNIT=11,FILE=TRIM(MAIN_FILE_NAME),STATUS='old',iostat=E_IO)
    READ(UNIT=11,FMT='(A)') DUMMY !'<version="1.0"? byte_order="BigEndian>'
    READ(UNIT=11,FMT='(A)') DUMMY !'<NumberOfRealPoints="3">'
    READ(UNIT=11,FMT='(A)') DUMMY !'<DataArray type="Float32" NumberOfComponents="3" offset="0">'
    READ(UNIT=11,FMT='(A)') DUMMY !'<NumberOfIntValues="2">'
    READ(UNIT=11,FMT='(A)') DUMMY !'<DataArray type="Int32" NumberOfComponents="1" offset="40">'
    READ(UNIT=11,FMT='(A)') DUMMY !'<end text>'
    READ(UNIT=11,FMT='(A)') ONECH !'_'
    N_V = 3_I32*N_REAL_VAL
    !READ(UNIT=11) N_BYTE, (REAL_ARRAY_READ(I),I=1_I32,N_V)
    
    CLOSE(11)
    
    
END SUBROUTINE READ_FILE
```

However, I am not sure how to extract the numerical values of arrays from this binary file. Do I need to reopen the file as `UNFORMATTED` and somehow position reading after the text? Could you please help with correctly reading the values of `X, Y, Z, INT_ARRAY` (`REAL_ARRAY_READ, INT_ARRAY_READ` respectively)?

Comment: Be careful, this `convert='big_endian'` is not portable and not standard Fortran. However, you cannot just ignore it. If it has been used when creating those files, you do have to convert the byte order somehow. And you certainly do have to open the file in a similar way it was opened when writing it. That means stream unformatted. If you are unsure how stream access works, this is the right time to study that. An answer here cannot give you the full understanding.

Comment: Also, since the file is stored as an XML file with a particular structure, you cannot just "read the data", you have to parse the file. Consider using some XML parsing library, because it appears you probably do not know much about parsing.

Comment: Anyway, I fear that showing all that in an answer here is really too much for this format. Someone could go through the hard work and write it for you, but it might only work for this specific case and not for all the cases you need. Note that you call "minimal reproducible example" is not really *reproducible*. You are leaving the relevant variables undefined.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава thnak you for your comments. I will try to come up with solution for this specific case I have and then try to generalize it for my project. I will look more into the stream access. I am not sure which relevant variables I left undefined in my code, so I will double check. The code compiles and runs for me.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the values are defined at the top.